# Use of multiple values in /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What is the use of three values in /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled

```
# cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
```

From the post below know what these values mean ,but what is the purpose of having all three values.

[CentOS 7 - When THP is disabled is it safe to ignore defrag setting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370799/centos-7-when-thp-is-disabled-is-it-safe-to-ignore-defrag-setting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enabled` entry shows all possible values which can be set; the current setting is the one between square brackets. Since the available options can vary depending on the kernel configuration, it’s useful to see what they are.

Comment: So the one in those square brackets is the active one.